# Blur to remove the noise after or before grayscale conversion?

Tags: python, opencv, opencv3.0

From the book `'Learning OpenCV 3 Computer Vision with Python - Second Edition'`, page 50

> For blurring, let's use medianBlur(), which is effective in removing
>   digital video noise, especially in color images. For edge-finding,
>   let's use Laplacian(), which produces bold edge lines, especially in
>   grayscale images. After applying medianBlur(), but before applying
>   Laplacian(), we should convert the image from BGR to grayscale.

I'm having troubles trying to understand why it suggests to apply the grayscale conversion after the blur step. I've got a code where I apply first the grayscale conversion, and I'm curious about this.

Any clues?

Comment: Because `cv::laplacian()` needs a single channel gray scale image.

Comment: @ZdaR it has something to do with the accuracy of the blur in the grayscale image?

Comment: I didn't exactly get that ?

Comment: @ZdaR The text says that the grayscale conversion is done after applying median blur. My question is if there is any reasons to not to do the conversion before the blur.

Comment: No it's completely upto you, Input image can implicitly be a gray scale image. Generally input images are in BGR example, hence the assumption of that text.

Comment: It's actually likely faster to do the blur after conversion to greyscale because there's only one channel instead of three.